# Is this considered a local search algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm

I read this online

Stochastic hill climbing is a local search algorithm that involves making random modifications to an existing solution and accepting the modification only if it results in better results than the current working solution.

So if I have strings of something and each character in the string corresponds go something. Example: a string of 1 and 0s. 1 means it has something 0 means it doesn’t.

If I randomly replace some of those characters and check to see if it’s a better solution (and replace it if needed) is this a local search?

Comment: Yes, but the core idea is about *locality*. So allowing to replace all positions at once (equivalent to generating a new random solution) defeats the purpose of a *neighborhood* which should encode some locality (e.g. neighborhood: i can jump as long as only 3 positions change).

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I understand that now. What I’m wondering is how often should this process happen? Should I do a local search for every string, or is there a rate?

Comment: I think we have to be careful here as this question in the comment touches completeness / incompleteness. The core questions is: Do you recognize, that you evaluated the full neighborhood? Yes and there has been no improvement? Stop -> Local-convergence! So a neighborhood composed of 3 bitflips means there is no point in doing > 8 evaluations (when none was improving). If you generate those by a pattern, e.g. lexicographic -> easy: count 8 steps. If you randomly-sample those: well... without keeping a memory of the samples you won't be able to *prove* that you evaluated the full neighborhood.

Comment: Incomplete methods for sure can be a valid thing to do. But in this case, you need to tune your steps / time before giving up.